# Eclipse crash after Windows update

Tags: java, android, eclipse, crash, cocos2d-x

I will try to explain this issue as best as I can because I am not really sure where to start. I am currently running Windows 7 Ultimate and last night my computer restarted automatically while I was working in eclipse to do automatic updates. After the computer restarted I loaded up eclipse and got the following error:

```
The 'xtext.common.types.originalEditorSelector' extension from plug-in 'org.eclipse.xtext.common.types.shared' to the 'org.eclipse.ui.ide.editorAssociationOverride' extension point failed to load the editor association override class.
Plug-in org.eclipse.xtext.common.types.shared was unable to load class org.eclipse.xtext.common.types.shared.SharedCommonTypesExecutableExtensionFactory.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.xtext.common.types.shared (563).
```

If I look at the error log there are things like this:

```
eclipse.buildId=v22.6.2-1085508
java.version=1.8.0_05
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product -product com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product -data C:\Users\James\workspace -product com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product

This is a continuation of log file C:\Users\James\workspace\.metadata\.bak_7.log
Created Time: 2014-11-15 12:07:56.205

Error
Sat Nov 15 12:21:04 EST 2014


java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/ui/texteditor/SimpleMarkerAnnotation
    at org.eclipse.debug.ui.DebugUITools.getToggleBreakpointsTargetManager(DebugUITools.java:1109)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.actions.breakpoints.RetargetBreakpointAction.getAdapter(RetargetBreakpointAction.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.actions.RetargetAction.selectionChanged(RetargetAction.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.actions.breakpoints.RetargetBreakpointAction.selectionChanged(RetargetBreakpointAction.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PluginAction.refreshEnablement(PluginAction.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PluginAction.selectionChanged(PluginAction.java:277)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PluginAction.selectionChanged(PluginAction.java:299)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.SelectionService.notifyListeners(SelectionService.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.SelectionService.access$3(SelectionService.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.SelectionService$1.selectionChanged(SelectionService.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.SelectionAggregator$2.run(SelectionAggregator.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.SelectionAggregator.notifyListeners(SelectionAggregator.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.SelectionAggregator.access$5(SelectionAggregator.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.SelectionAggregator$7$1.run(SelectionAggregator.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.RunAndTrack.runExternalCode(RunAndTrack.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.SelectionAggregator$7.changed(SelectionAggregator.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.update(TrackableComputationExt.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.processScheduled(EclipseContext.java:334)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.set(EclipseContext.java:348)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.SelectionServiceImpl.setSelection(SelectionServiceImpl.java:30)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.selectionChanged(CompatibilityPart.java:437)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer$2.run(Viewer.java:164)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer.fireSelectionChanged(Viewer.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.updateSelection(StructuredViewer.java:2188)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handleSelect(StructuredViewer.java:1211)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$4.widgetSelected(StructuredViewer.java:1241)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.fireSelectionEvent(OpenStrategy.java:239)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$4(OpenStrategy.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.handleEvent(OpenStrategy.java:403)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1057)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4170)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3759)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1113)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:997)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
Caused by: org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter$TerminatingClassNotFoundException: An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.ui.editors (473).
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:469)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:461)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:679)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:478)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:469)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:461)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.objectteams.otequinox.internal.MasterTeamLoader$TeamClassRecord.newInstance(MasterTeamLoader.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.objectteams.otequinox.internal.MasterTeamLoader.instantiateLoadedTeams(MasterTeamLoader.java:314)
    at org.eclipse.objectteams.otequinox.TransformerPlugin.internalInstantiateTeams(TransformerPlugin.java:558)
    at org.eclipse.objectteams.otequinox.TransformerPlugin.instantiateTeams(TransformerPlugin.java:503)
    at org.eclipse.objectteams.otequinox.internal.hook.BaseBundleRole.endActivation(BaseBundleRole.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.objectteams.otequinox.internal.hook.BaseBundleRole.endActivation(BaseBundleRole.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.objectteams.otequinox.internal.hook.TransformerHook.watchBundle(TransformerHook.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.BaseAdaptor$3.watchBundle(BaseAdaptor.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:410)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:478)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:469)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:461)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.objectteams.otdt.internal.compiler.adaptor.AdaptorActivator$__OT__JavaCore.setClasspathContainer(AdaptorActivator.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.objectteams.otdt.internal.compiler.adaptor.AdaptorActivator._OT$JavaCore$setClasspathContainer$setClasspathContainer(AdaptorActivator.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore._OT$setClasspathContainer$chain(JavaCore.java)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.setClasspathContainer(JavaCore.java)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidClasspathContainerInitializer.initialize(AndroidClasspathContainerInitializer.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.initializeContainer(JavaModelManager.java:2873)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.getClasspathContainer(JavaModelManager.java:1908)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.getClasspathContainer(JavaCore.java:3251)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.resources.manager.ProjectClassLoader.getExternalJars(ProjectClassLoader.java:313)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.resources.manager.ProjectClassLoader.loadClassFromJar(ProjectClassLoader.java:271)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.resources.manager.ProjectClassLoader.findClass(ProjectClassLoader.java:80)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.resources.manager.CompiledResourcesMonitor.loadAndParseRClass(CompiledResourcesMonitor.java:217)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.resources.manager.CompiledResourcesMonitor.projectOpenedWithWorkspace(CompiledResourcesMonitor.java:192)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.resources.manager.GlobalProjectMonitor.addProjectListener(GlobalProjectMonitor.java:427)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.resources.manager.CompiledResourcesMonitor.setupMonitor(CompiledResourcesMonitor.java:64)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.resources.manager.ResourceManager.setup(ResourceManager.java:120)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.AdtPlugin.startEditors(AdtPlugin.java:1539)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.AdtPlugin.start(AdtPlugin.java:265)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:478)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:469)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.loadClass(BundleLoader.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.loadClass(BundleHost.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadClass(AbstractBundle.java:1212)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.instantiateBuilder(BuildManager.java:906)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.initializeBuilder(BuildManager.java:859)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager._OT$getBuilder$orig(BuildManager.java:545)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager._OT$getBuilder$chain(BuildManager.java)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager._OT$getBuilder$chain(BuildManager.java)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager._OT$getBuilder$chain(BuildManager.java)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.getBuilder(BuildManager.java)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.getBuilder(BuildManager.java:574)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:244)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:299)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:302)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:358)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.ui.internal.editors.text.EditorsPlugin.start() of bundle org.eclipse.ui.editors.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:734)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:478)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:109)
    ... 116 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Invalid thread access
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4397)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4312)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4283)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.error(Display.java:1258)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.checkDevice(Display.java:764)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.disposeExec(Display.java:1203)
    at org.eclipse.jface.resource.ColorRegistry.hookDisplayDispose(ColorRegistry.java:268)
    at org.eclipse.jface.resource.ColorRegistry.<init>(ColorRegistry.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.jface.resource.ColorRegistry.<init>(ColorRegistry.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.themes.WorkbenchThemeManager.<init>(WorkbenchThemeManager.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.themes.WorkbenchThemeManager.getInstance(WorkbenchThemeManager.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.getThemeManager(Workbench.java:3225)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.editors.text.EditorsPlugin.start(EditorsPlugin.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    ... 122 more
```

I cant do anything at all in Eclipse and I have tried the following to fix it with no results:

1. system restore
2. Adding -clean in the eclipse.ini

I am not sure if this matters but this is a cocos2dx 2.1.5 project that I was working on. Another weird thing that happen as well after this windows update is that firefox will not even start. THe error I get is:

Couldn't load XPCOM

I am not sure if these errors are related but I thought I would mention it. I am really worried about losing my progress on this 7 month long project and I was wondering if anyone had any insight on how to help me. If I must reinstall eclipse could someone explain how I could do that while keeping my workspace in tact. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try restarting eclipse after removing .lock file from .metadata directory of your work space. I have faced similar problem and it worked after removing the .lock file even though I got different stack trace in .log file.

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar error. Basically it seemed to be a problem with the workspace. I had to create another workspace for eclipse to make eclipse working again.

I hope it helps